# Calculate offset of base class at compile time

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

I was wondering about whether the calculation of a base class offset is possible at compile time. Sure, it is fairly easy to do at runtime since the capabilities of `static_cast` can be leveraged and the offset is simply the difference between the base pointer to the pointer to the derived class.

My first attempt to get this at compile time looked something like the following:

```
struct InterfaceRoot {};

struct IInterface1 : InterfaceRoot {
    virtual void MethodI1() = 0;
};

struct IInterface2 : InterfaceRoot {
    virtual void MethodI2() = 0;
};

class CClass : public IInterface1, public IInterface2 {
    virtual void MethodI1() override { /* do something */ }
    virtual void MethodI2() override { /* do something */ }     
};

int main() {

    CClass instance;

    constexpr int offsetI1 = 0; //first base class has no offset
    constexpr int offsetI2 = sizeof(IInterface1);

    //check pointer values against static_cast
    IInterface1* pI1 = reinterpret_cast<IInterface1*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&instance) + offsetI1);
    IInterface2* pI2 = reinterpret_cast<IInterface2*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&instance) + offsetI2);

    IInterface1* pI1_static_cast = static_cast<IInterface1*>(&instance);
    IInterface2* pI2_static_cast = static_cast<IInterface2*>(&instance);

    return 0;
}
```

Here, `pI1` and `pI1_static_cast` are equal as expected. Howerver, `pI2` and `pI2_static_cast` are not equal!?

I can fix this by either adding a virtual function to `InterfaceRoot` or leaving it out alltogether. What is the reason for this?

If I setup the inheritance tree like this it works with the aforementioned method:

```
struct InterfaceRoot {
    virtual ~InterfaceRoot() {}
};

struct IInterface1 : InterfaceRoot {
    virtual void MethodI1() = 0;
};

struct IInterface2 : InterfaceRoot {
    virtual void MethodI2() = 0;
};

class CClass : public IInterface1, public IInterface2 {
    virtual void MethodI1() override { /* do something */ }
    virtual void MethodI2() override { /* do something */ }
};
```

Does anybody know why this is? I am using Visual Studio 2017 by the way. Is there another way to achieve my goal at compile time, or am I better off calculating the ofsets at runtime and have a small runtime overhead?

#### Edit:

A working runtime implementation could look something like this:

```
template<typename Derived, typename Base>
inline int CalcBaseOffset() {
    const static int s_off = (reinterpret_cast<char*>(static_cast<Base*>(reinterpret_cast<Derived*>(0x10000000))) - reinterpret_cast<char*>(0x10000000));
    return s_off;
};

int main() {
    //...

    int offsetI1_RT = CalcBaseOffset<CClass, IInterface1>();
    int offsetI2_RT = CalcBaseOffset<CClass, IInterface2>();

    // add offsets to pointer like in the code sample above

}
```

This approach yields accurate results, which however come at the cost of a small runtime overhead (The runtime overhead is acceptable if there is no way to calculate the offsets at compiletime to eliminate this overhead).

Comment: just out of curiosity, would you please give us the actual hex values of all four pointers in your `main()` ?

Comment: @Mike Nakis `pI1 = 0x0077fe78`, `pI1_static_cast = 0x0077fe78`, `pI2 = 0x0077fe7c`, `pI2_static_cast = 0x0077fe80`

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this? I find it hard to find a use-case for this.

Comment: I want to implement a COM-like interface structure and I want the function `QueryInterface`(The cross compiler version of `dynamic_cast`) to be automatically generated by a template class. But in order to cast the `this` pointer to a base class pointer, I need the offset. The problem is, that casts to pointer values do not work at compile time, so I have to look for other possibilities or implement the algorithm at runtime where I would incur a runtime overhead each time I called `QueryInterface`.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler may introduce padding in the `CClas` between the base classes `IInterface1` and `IInterface2`.

Basically<sup>X</sup>: *sizeof(CClas) >= sizeof(IInterface1) + sizeof(IInterface2)*

The following statement may then yield to a wrong address:

> IInterface2* pI2 =
> reinterpret_cast<IInterface2*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&instance) +
> offsetI2

---

<sup>X</sup>Note that this may not hold if the base classes have no `virtual` *member functions* and are empty (i.e., have no *data members*) due to the [Empty Base Optimization](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Empty_Base_Optimization).

Comment: Is there a way I can get the size of this padding?

Comment: I just tested this... `sizeof(CClass) = 8` which is exactly equal to `sizeof(IInterface1) + sizeof(IInterface2)`!?

Comment: `IInterface2 *pl2 = &instance;` should store in `pl2` the address of the 2nd base.

Comment: Yes sure, but this calculation happens at runtime, whereas I want the offset at compile time...

Comment: No, this calculation happens at compile-time, because the compiler is aware of the size of each object at compile-time.